# live game, use memory or DB or both?

Tags: node.js, chess

Currenty i'm working on creating a chess app with nodejs & socket.io

now the running games information are stored in an array like this:

```
  games[token] = {
    'creator': socket,
    'players': [],
    'interval': null,
    'timeout': timeout,
    'FEN' : '',
    'PGN' : ''
  };
```

The question is : Is better to save games info to DB at the creation of games and change the values of fields move by move, or save every game after finish?
Which is better approach?

Comment: What is your criteria for better? Scalability? Performance? Auditability? Reliability? Capacity? You'd need to put some numbers/metrics against these to get a sensible answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wait until the end of a game to save state then you run the risk of losing it if something like a server crash occurs. Think unhandled exception or something outside of your control like a container restart or something worse.

Persist every bit of data that you want recoverable as soon as possible. I could imagine an rpg in which it wasn't super important to always be able to recover the players exact position on a map. It seems you'd always want to be able to recover the state of your chess games.

Comment: and if there was 500 running games (for example) like chess.com or other huge traffic web sites, then can a DB engine response in time? time lags don't happen?

Comment: can Redis help in this type?

Comment: You can use any data store you like. Redis is fast but mongo should be fine too. I wouldn't worry too much about database latency.

Comment: Can use React/MongoDB and Mysql together? they play a cache store role and finally save finished games in a mysql table?

Comment: It's up to you.  I mention mongo because it plays nicely with json. I would suggest  so that you start simply with one data store and see what happens as you grow.

Answer (score 2):

If you want crash proof implementation cheapest way is to write every move in journal log. When game ends you save the state and discard journal. On every game start load the state and then check if there is anything in the journal, if yes just play back the events.

Journal can be in database, disk or some light weight DB like Redis.